# Dealing with duplicates while looping through one Dataframe and searching in a second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm currently looping through one Dataframe (Total_Data), looking up a value in a second DataFrame (IT_Data), and calculating a result based on values from each. The DataFrames are the same size, columns, etc., but their timestamps and indices don't align. So I'm searching IT_Data for the Total_Data value, then subtracting one column from another to get the result. The end result is the Total_Data['3'] value (BP_Shear), with a new value based on Total_Data['2'] - IT_Data['2'] (BP_Dis). The idea is to graph the difference between the two test results.

The issue is there are duplicates in both DataFrames and I'd like to include them. But when I find the matching value in IT_Data it always uses the first iteration, so the result is off.

This likely isn't explained well, so below is the code with comments and some results to show what I mean.

```
        # Iterates through the total shear stresses, index is the index, Total_Shear is the row.
        # '3' is the shear stress column, '2' is the displacement column
        for index, Total_Shear in Total_Data.iterrows():
            print(index, Total_Shear['3'])
            

            # Total_Shear['3'] value being looked for in the intact shear series IT_DATA['3']
            # If it is not found, continue skips the remaining code, we go to the next value
            if IT_Data[IT_Data['3'] == Total_Shear['3']].empty:
                continue

            # The row number in the intact data series for where the Total_Shear value was found
            # We need this to know where the displacement will be, it can be numerous locations
            row_number = IT_Data[IT_Data['3'] == Total_Shear['3']].index

            # Total_Shear['3'] is the shear stress value being used in the final plot
            BP_Shear.append(Total_Shear['3'])

            # The total displacement, the first value should 0.019 (from 013)
            Tot_Dis = Total_Shear['2']

            # The intact displacement, the first value should be 0.005 (from 012)
            IT_Dis = IT_Data.iloc[row_number[0], 0]

            # The joint displacement is the total displacement minus the intact displacement
            BP_Dis.append(Tot_Dis - IT_Dis)
            print(Tot_Dis, IT_Dis, Tot_Dis - IT_Dis)

            # Drops the row from the intact shears once used, to use the next in line then instead
            # IT_Data.drop(row_number[0])
            print(IT_Data.iloc[row_number[0]])
```

I've tried using drop with inplace=True and the result is it skips ahead in IT_Data. If I don't do anything (or use inplace=False), it always uses the first iteration it finds in IT_Data. For example:

Total_Shear['3'] = -0.1 occurs twice, the displacement for the first occurrence is 0.034, and 0.036 for the second.

IT_Data['3'] = -0.1 occurs twice, the displacement for the first occurence is 0.023, and 0.024 for the second.

I would like this to run twice as below:
0.034 - 0.023
0.036 - 0.024

Instead, it will subtract 0.023 both times, like below:
0.034 - 0.023
0.036 - 0.023

Without drop it always uses 0.023 when finding -0.1 in IT_Data, but when including the drop() function is will skip ahead and use the displacement value another row down.